# How do I get the region endpoints from the Amazon SimpleDB API

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

So its easy to get the Amazon EC2 region endpoints simply via an API call (DescribeRegions)

But how do I do this with the SimpleDB API, there is no obvious (to me) call. (and the endpoints are different, so I can't just use the EC2 one's)

Edit: Oh, I'm using the .NET API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no SimpleDB API calls similiar to DescribeRegions. The documentation is the only source for the public endpoints. Currently there are 4 of them:

- **sdb.amazonaws.com** — Endpoint located in the US-East (Northern Virginia) Region
- **sdb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com** — Endpoint located in the US-West (Northern California) Region
- **sdb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com** — Endpoint located in the EU (Ireland) Region
- **sdb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com** — Endpoint located in the Asia Pacific (Singapore) Region

Here is a direct link to the doc page that maintains the most up to date list of these endpoints. If new ones are added, you'll know by looking here:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/Endpoints.html

Comment: Thanks for that, I already know that page. But short of html scraping that page I will have to have my app maintain region end points either hard coded or in a config file...not a very good long term solution when I should be able to just query the service for them :-(

Comment: I agree, that would be a useful API call. The use case I see is with tooling, providing a report or dashboard tool able to include all available regions. I wonder what the data storage use cases would be, though. Unlike EC2, you can't just fire up an existing AMI in a new region.

Comment: It seems that the mapping for all new domains is direct - so you special case a few, the for new ones the endpoint will match the s3 endpoint. But is that in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the mapping for all new domains is direct - so you special case a few (EU, us east), then for new ones the endpoint will match the s3 endpoint. But is that in the docs?

It worked for me when tokyo was announced. Code went right on working and allowed it as an endpoint.